# Problema al subir información a un dataset con la api de Carto

Tags: python, sql

Muy buenas. Estoy cacharreando con la API de Carto. Estoy haciendo una prueba de un código en Python que sea capaz de subir información a un dataset. Un código muy sencillito que envía la siguiente query:

'''
query = "INSERT INTO url_fotos (the_geom,name,description,url,tiempo) VALUES ((40.40876, -3.69245),'Atocha','Prueba desde python','https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/71/Estaci%C3%B3n_de_Atocha_-_felipe_gabaldon.jpg/800px-Estaci%C3%B3n_de_Atocha_-_felipe_gabaldon.jpg','2020-01-22T08:53:05Z')"
'''

Y que me devuelve el siguiente error:

some error ocurred ['column "the_geom" is of type geometry but expression is of type record']

No hay demasiada información ni demasiados ejemplos que haya encontrado, si alguien sabe por dónde pueden ir los tiros para hacer que esto funcione se lo agradezco de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Nada, resuelto.

Estaba pasando la referencia de latitud y longitud mal, al parecer hay que pasar la instrucción de crear un punto en un sistema de coordenadas determinado, en este caso con la instrucción ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(lat, long),sistema_de_coordenadas), quedando así:

query = "INSERT INTO url_fotos (the_geom,name,description,url,tiempo) VALUES (ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-3.69245, 40.40876),4326),'Atocha','Prueba desde python','https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/71/Estaci%C3%B3n_de_Atocha_-_felipe_gabaldon.jpg/800px-Estaci%C3%B3n_de_Atocha_-_felipe_gabaldon.jpg','2020-01-22T08:53:05Z')"

El sistema de coordenadas en este caso es el 4326.